# Grails domain class. Random field

Tags: mysql, grails, random, dsl

I have this Grails domain class:

```
class Main {

    Random r;

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and in database i see, that `Random` its -  `tinyblob`.

In ORM DSL Documentation i not find indormation about this.
So, maybe, somebody can say me, why `Random` its a `tinyblob`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a default mapping for an unknown class that will serialize into byte stream.
Here's an [example](http://www.grails.org/version/description-375/9?update=descriptionTab) of user type mapping, you can implement Hibernate mapper and register it in Config.groovy.

Still, I believe what you need is to declare the field transient:

```
class Main {
    Random r = new Random()
    static transients = ['r']
}
```

or just to have it private - private fields are not mapped by default.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a `transient` keyword in Groovy?

Comment: No AFAIK, what would it do out of ORM context? It's just a conventional name for a property. If you write `static`, you can omit `def`. Groovy is dynamic, so `transients` variable, though declared as Object, is freely used as a collection of String.